# audioread in Matlab on Unix machine

Tags: matlab, unix, audio

I am trying to read an audio file into Matlab and when I run the command

```
[y, Fs] = audioread('Recording10.wma')
```

in Matlab on my Windows 7 laptop it runs without any problems, but when I try to run it on our clusters I get the following error:

> {Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file. What() is: ..
>
> Error in multimedia.internal.audio.file.PluginManager (line 148)
>               mexPluginManager('initializePluginManager',obj.PluginPath);
>
> Error in audioread (line 124)
>       exception = PluginManager.convertPluginException(exception, ... }

I would appreciate any suggestions or advice you could give me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately audioread does not support reading .wma files on Linux or Mac machines:

- [audioread filename Input argument](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html#inputarg_filename)

The error message you are getting here is not very informative either.  Which version of MATLAB are you using?  I believe in newer versions the error message is more helpful:

```
[y, Fs] = audioread('test.wma')
```

In R2013b for example the error message reads

```
Error using audioread (line 127)
The file type is not supported
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. Yes, that error is a lot more helpful. I am not sure which version is running on the cluster. I thought it was R2013a, but am not sure.